# Assembly to C Translation: Order of Local variables?

Tags: c, assembly

Okay so I am trying to translate this assembly into C.

So my confusion is at line 7, where it seems that 2 * x is stored in the variable i. But this does not seem to follow the order of the C code. Am I interpreting this wrong? Is it actually storing 2 * x into val?

Assembly:

[image: Assembly version]

C:

[image: C version]

Comment: That would depend on what compiler this course is using.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your C code but the assembler code is clear enough. It adds the argument to itself and stores it in a local variable.

EDIT: Now I see the C code. It seems that at address -4( %ebp ) there is variable val, that is the code correspomds to

```
int val = 2 * x;
```

By the way it is easy to check what is the order of variables in the stack. Write a simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a[1] = { 0 };
    int b = 0;

    a[1] = 15;

    printf( "%d\n", b );
    printf( "%d\n", a[0] );


    return 0;
}
```

If 15 will be outputed then the compiler places variables on the stack in the reverse order. I tested this code with GCC at www.ideone.com and got the expected result that is

```
15
0
```

Comment: I thought that the addresses of local variables decreased in the order that the local variables appeared? Is it the opposite? Or is there some exception since i is not assigned anything at declaration? In other words, I thought that "i" would be at -4(%ebp) and that "val" would be at -8(%ebp)?

Comment: @Lucas I can not say exactly. I think it depends on the assembler, You can analyse the full code that to determine the correct variables' order. At least the stack is decreased by 16 bytes. So there are more than 2 local varaibeld of type int.

Comment: 0 Was outputted. So does this mean that val = 2 * x?

Comment: You could always output your disassembly interleaved with source code, no optimizations, access two stack-allocated variables, and check their offsets to see what order they're allocated in. But it's more likely that they're allocated in the order they're listed because there's no reason not to, and -4(%ebp) references val, not i.